# função indefinida no window.onload?

Tags: javascript, html

bem eu declarei uma função em um arquivo javascript

arquivo javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
   function func(x,y){
      //faz operacoes em x e y e nao retorna nada
   }
}
```

porem no arquivo html,quando eu quero chamar essa funcao passando os parametros x e y

arquivo html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     func(2,3);
</script>
```

ele da erro no arquivo html dizendo que a função está indefinida,eu ja tentei fazer algo do tipo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
       func(2,3);
    }
</script>
```

so que nao vai,ele da erro mesmo assim dizendo que eu nao declarei a função,porém eu declarei a função em um arquivo js separado,alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?agradeço quem puder ajudar

nota:eu estou usando variaveis globais,além do fato do meu algoritmo ser muito grande para colocar no html,então se puderem me indicar uma forma de passar os parametros de uma funcao javascript no html me ajudaria bastante

Comment: Não entendi qual o motivo de `window.onload` no arquivo js, use isto no HTML.

Comment: Qual a ordem dos scripts no HTML?

Comment: ora a mesma ordem que você está vendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque a função `func` está definida apenas dentro do escopo de `window.onload`. Você precisa declarar ela antes de chamá-la, conforme esse exemplo:

```
//Coloquei um alert apenas para fins de teste
function func(x,y){
    alert(x + y)
}

//Aqui a função estará declarada quando chama-la
window.onload = function(){
    func(2,3);
}

//Assim, poderá chamá-la em outro lugar, por exemplo clique de botão
document.getElementById("botao").click = function () { func(2,3); }
```

Se você declara-la dentro do `onload`, ela estará visível apenas ali, e caso você chame ela de qualquer outro lugar na página, ela não existirá, por isso deu o erro do undefined

Comment: vlw mano era oque eu tava precisando saber